# Coordinates-based text display upon an image with Django's template system

Tags: django, image, excel, coordinate

I am currently trying to update an excel-map with data fetched from Django and display it on a page linked to my admin.

The excel-"map" :

[image]

Using the xlrd & cie libs I'm working on the fetching / updating data part but a fellow dev told me he would have used an image instead.

My Question is : How could I do such a thing ? Displaying a copy of the above spreadsheet and using row-based coordinates to write the data I want ? (Text data)

Do you guys know a way to work easily with coordinate-based text display in Django's templates ?

Thanks for any help you can give me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the PIL library. It was finally quite easy and could be summarized by the following code :

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

im = Image.open('path/to/map.png')
font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf', 7)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

draw.text((x, y), sentence, font=font, fill='black')

response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/png')
im.save(response, 'PNG')

return response
```

Logic behind x and y is irrelevant here, but bear in mind that they start quite illogically on the upper left corner of the image and go from there to right and bottom with positive numbers.